# Do we need to initialize @mock object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I m using mockito for junit. I have doubt while creating mock of object.
I have class called DBConnect. Where I need database properties like dbname, credentials etc.
This class is used by PatientDetails. Now when I am writing junit for PatientDetails. So I am using following code.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  
   public class PatientDetailsTest {
      @Mock
      DBConnect dbConnect

      @Before
      public void setUp()
      {

      PatientDetails testClass = new PatientDetails();
      testClass.setDBConnect(dbConnect);
      }
   }
```

I can not get correct result with this.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate. Start by posting compilable, correctly indented code. Then explain precisely what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: What results are you trying to get?

Comment: It is not retrieving query result form database.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems fine to me. I've extended it slightly to include a test, so that it can be run. This works fine:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PatientDetailsTest {
    @Mock
    DBConnect dbConnect;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(dbConnect.sayHello()).thenReturn("works for me");
        PatientDetails testClass = new PatientDetails();
        testClass.setDBConnect(dbConnect);
    }        

    @Test
    public void testname() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    private static interface DBConnect {
        String sayHello();
    }

    private static class PatientDetails {
        public void setDBConnect(DBConnect dbConnect) {
            System.out.println(dbConnect.sayHello());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
works for me
foo
```